# *ngIf equivalent in DevExtreme?

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme

I'm currently working on a webapp, and I'm supposed to do it in DevExtreme. Keep in mind that I don't have that much coding experience and this is my first time doing anything with DevExtreme.

Very basically I need something to only be displayed if a certain condition is met. I know I could do it with CSS and styling through Typescript, but I thought it'd be cleaner doing it with an if statement directly inside of the HTML (also it'd be nicer to just use the functionality in the future if it exists instead of building it myself every time).

The only issue is, no matter where I look or what I google, I can't seem to find anything. Since it's still entirely possible I'm just blind, I thought I'd try my luck here.

Since DevExtreme is Angular based (at least for me), I tried it with the normal *ngIf, I avoided doing anything concerning Inline Styling through typescript.

Comment: provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ngIf does actually exist in DevExtreme, I simply got an error I misunderstood while trying to implement it, as I had imported the module incorrectly.